# Application layer protocol header fields in Java

Tags: java

I hope the question is suitable for here. I've designed an application layer protocol, say similar to HTTP. How can I define, and set the header fields in Java? Overall, I just want to write a simple client-server program that transfers "Hello World" string, but using my own protocol.

Assume header fields are similar to the following. So the "Hello World!" data comes after this header.

[image]

Comment: I just have a simple piece of client-server code. I don't know how to set/change the header fields. That's my question.

Comment: which web server are you using?

Comment: If you defined that protocol yourself you should be able to set the header accordingly, e.g. by first collecting them into some expanded fields (e.g. enums, strings, ints etc.) and when sending the header you pack those fields into your header format.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. But my problem is with the header itself. How should I even set the header, or replace mine with the current one?

Comment: I don't get it: you're able to design a protocol but don't know how to write the header to a stream (creating and filling a header object shouldn't be any issue)? And what do you mean with "replace mine with the current one" - isn't your header the one you want to use?

Comment: Yes. What I meant of designing was on paper, not on code! My question is with real implementation in Java. I was wondering if there might be some libraries or API for creating self-defined headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write to a socket, you're writing an stream of bytes.  It's common, as in the table you included in your question, to start that stream with a standard series of bytes that gives the information needed to make sense of the remaining stream.

For example, of you simply want to send a string the minimum you'd need to add would be the string length like this:

```
|message length|data|
```

Which could be written like this:

```
String data = "Hello, world!";

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length + Integer.BYTES);
buffer.putInt(data.length);    
buffer.put(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
buffer.flip();

channel.write(buffer);
```

Adding in additional *header* information is no different, you just need to define a format for it in the stream.

You might for example use a format like this

```
|message length|header count|header size|header type|header data|data|
```

Which could be written like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> headers = ...
String data = "Hello, world - look at my headers!";

int headerBuffersLength = 0;
List<ByteBuffer> headerBuffers = new ArrayList<>();

for(Integer headerType : headers.keySet())
{
  String headerData = headers.get(headerType);

  ByteBuffer headerBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocation(headerData.size + Integer.BYTES + Integer.BYTES);
  headerBuffer.putInt(headerData.length);
  headerBuffer.putInt(headerType);
  headerBuffer.put(headerData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  headerBuffer.flip();

  headerBuffers.add(headerBuffer);

  headerBuffersLength += headerBuffer.limit();
}

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length + headerBuffersLength + Integer.BYTES + Integer.BYTES);
buffer.putInt(data.length + headerBuffersLength);    
buffer.putInt(headerBuffers.size());

for (ByteBuffer headerBuffer : headerBuffers)
{
  buffer.put(headerBuffer);
}

buffer.put(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
buffer.flip();

channel.write(buffer);
```

That's the basics, the code is very simple to write, but you might want to look at [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) if you're doing anything more complicated.

Comment: Thanks Nick. So basically the header should be simply added ahead manually, just before the data itself. That can be considered a header! I thought in Java headers are predefined and added automatically, unless we use APIs to modify them!

Comment: The exact format is up to you, if you're writing to a socket, so it's just bytes and there's no concept of headers unless you define it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. It is quite common that this kind of specification comes with an `xsd`. If that is the case, you can use JAXB2 to parse it and create a set of Java Classes.

If that is not the case, may be you have the specification in such way you can do text processing and extract attributes and types to automate Java Class construction, using `grep`, `sed`, and so on.

If finally you have to build the Java Classes on your own, I will do something like following:

```
package my.package.ams;

public class ASMHeader {
    private Integer version = null;
    private Integer msgType = null;
    private Integer priority = null;
    ...

    public String getVersionString (){
        return String.format("%02d", (version != null)?version:0);
    }

    public Integer getVersion(){
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version){
        if(version >= 0 and version < 100){
            this.version = version;
        }
    }

    public Integer getMsgType(){
        return msgType;
    }

    public void setMsgType(Integer MsgType){
        if(msgType >= 0 and msgType < 5){
            this.msgType = msgType;
        }
    }

    //And so on

    ....
}
```

Finally processing rules are not shown in yournpic, but you will have to understand and implements.

Take into account the possibility to thrown exception where `version`, `msgType` and other variables, doesn't meet the rules expressed in the document.

Hope it helps!